# Pulley and cables, force needed to maintain equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]
The answer is 16 N, but I am not sure how to solve this. Can anyone help explain with a diagram? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please do not edit a question after it has been answered in a way that makes it impossble to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a hint. If the tension in the string through a pulley is $ T $. Then the tension in the string to which the pulley is attached will be $ 2T $. This is because since the pulley is massless, the net force acting on the pulley will always be zero. Here, both ends of the string through the pulley is downwards, and hence, if the tension at each end of the string is $ T $, then there is a net downward force of $ 2T $ on the pulley. But, since the net force on a pulley would be zero, the tension in the  string to which the pulley is attached would be $ 2T $ upwards. Hence the forces cancels out.

[image]

With this you can find the tension in each string with respect to $ T $.

Note: Since the system is at equilibrium, the tension in the string through the third pulley would also be equivalent to $ F $  since it is the force acting at one end of the string.

I guess this would help you to solve the problem on your own :)

The free body diagram :

[image]

Comment: I have added the FBD you asked. Sorry, for the untidy drawings. If you want me to redraw, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

$$
T=2x_1\\
x_1=2x_2\\
x_2=2F\\
x_1+x_2+F=14
$$

$$
\frac T8 =F\\
\frac T2+\frac T4+\frac T8=14
$$

$$
T=\frac{14 \cdot 8}{7}=16
$$